# Does the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(y)$ always equal zero even when a phase is included?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

The following is true when $n, m$ are integers:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(mt)\sin(nt)\text{d}t = 0$$

But is it also true when arbitrary phases are included? For example:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(mt+\theta)\sin(nt+\phi)\text{d}t = 0$$

Comment: Can you provide more information about why this question is of interest to you?  In what context?  Have you tried graphing specific choices for $\theta$ and $\phi$?  Please do some exploration, and come back to fill in more context.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been working for 2 days straight, and can't think this one through. I'm close to finishing my work so I can sleep, and knowing that I'm correct (I believe it's not true) would allow me to be done

Comment: I gave you some obvious suggestions; suppose, e.g., that $\theta = \frac \pi 6$ and $\phi = \frac \pi8$.  Graph each function and check out to see whether it is true with those phases.  Then try another pair of arbitrary angles.  And you haven't mentioned anything regarding why this question is of interest to you.  Surely you can do that in two days time?  Also add to your post why you believe it is not true.

Comment: Not really. I'm doing it now because it has only just come up now. If I had two days for just this problem, I'd have found an example. Like I said, I'm too tired to think clearly. I confused myself when working on a related question earlier involving the symmetry of sin and cosine which relate to simplifications of fourier series, and asking here became a sanity check. That's all I have to say.

Comment: This site is not to be mistaken with a *homework completion service*, Foreanlegion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take $n=m=1$ and $\theta=\pi$ and $\phi=\pi/2$; you'll get
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(t+\pi)\sin(t+\pi/2) \text{d}t=-\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t,m,n,\theta,\phi)=\cos (mt+\theta) \sin (n t + \theta), \quad m,n \in \text{Integers}.$

If $m \ne n$, then yes,  $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(t,m,n,\theta,\phi)\, dt =0.$$

If $m=n$,
$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(t,m,m,\theta,\phi)=\frac{1}{4m} [\cos (\theta+\phi) - \cos(4 m\pi + \theta + \phi) - 4m \pi \sin (\theta-\pi)]=\pi\sin (\phi-\theta).$$

This is not equal to zero, other than some degenerate cases ($\phi=\theta$, $\phi=\theta-\pi$, etc.)